Get bounding boxes of libraries using overpass turbo
I am trying to get the bounding boxes for each building libraries are in. However, my query is very unreliable.
Here is my query used in overpass turbo:
[out:json][timeout:1000];
area[name="Trondheim"]->.searchArea;

node["amenity"="library"](area.searchArea)->.libs;

(
  way["building"](area.searchArea)(bn.libs);
  relation["building"](area.searchArea)(bn.libs);
)->.structures;

(
  .libs;
  .structures;
);
out body geom;

Here is the result displaying that one library has bounding boxes, and one does not.

I have tried to download the norway.pbf file, and make a separate file for all the libraries, and using those two datasets to get the closest building bounding box the library is in.  However, this takes a lot of time unless i use libraries such as cuspatial and an A100 gpu in google colab. I doubt this is the optimal way.
Can this issue be solved by writing a single OSM query on a pbf file, or just using overpass turbo? If so, how can i do that?
I am not entirely sure if the data for the bounding box the library is in exists on overpass turbo. If that is the case, the complexity of this task probably increases by alot.

You can use the is_in operator, which provides all the areas that enclose a point. Together with this, the pivot statement is required:
[out:json][timeout:1000];
area[name="Trondheim"]->.searchArea;

node["amenity"="library"](area.searchArea)->.libs;
.libs is_in; 

wr["building"](pivot)->.structures;

(
  .libs;
  .structures;
);
out body geom;

Just a small addition: way and relation can be combined in one statement by use of wr.
